# mavericks intellij scala not configuring properly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, osx-mavericks

I followed this link http://austindw.com/blog/programming/running-intellij-jdk-1-7-scala-2-10-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks to configure scala in intellij but it says docs are not found.

[image]

any ideas why?

UPDATE:
I have checked the directory structure looks like the scala docs is inside doc folder, here is the pic but still it cant find it.
[image]

UPDATE:
I copied the files and folders from another api directory but still the same result, intellij couldnt find it.
Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: I also had difficulties to add the scaladoc with this interface. The workaround I found was to use the `Project Structure` view and add a link toward the scaladoc there in the `Libraries` panel. It works fine for me but I apparently have to use the online scaladoc.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me it was because the docs were indeed missing. Look inside /usr/local/opt/scala/idea/doc -- is there a scala-devel-docs subdirectory?

My solution was to download the API docs separately, and put them under the existing doc directory of my installation. You need to make sure that you create the hierarchy correctly: 
in your case /usr/local/opt/scala/idea/doc/scala-devel-docs/api -- you'll probably need to do some renaming after you extract the doc.

Here's a direct link to your version of the [docs](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.2/scala-docs-2.11.2.zip?_ga=1.50044774.1791972260.1408716413).

Comment: I have it already, I checked it after your answer. I have edited and added a pic of it but still it couldnt find it

Comment: @mad_programmer : I think I see the "problem". Notice in your installation `scala-devel-docs/api` contains **another** `api` directory. In mine it contains `jars`, `scala-compiler`, `scala-library` and `scala-reflect`. If I were you I would manually copy or move these one level up and try again.

Comment: I did as you said, but still the same result.

Comment: @mad_programmer: The only other thing I can think of is to do an `ls -l` all the way down the path to check permissions, but this is unlikely to be the problem unless you installed under a different account.

Comment: No I installed in the same account and I dont have many accounts either. This is so bizarre of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use IDE support to compilation and building, you might attract on yourself any sort of bug and the anger of software development divinities.

Please use a proper build tool to build software, such as **Gradle** or **Sbt**. SBT is native to Scala and Gradle can support it easily. **Maven** also has a Scala plugin.

Comment: I dont get you point here? Even if I use SBT I will have to set this up. And whats with Gradle I dont use Gradle. But if you were wondering that if I have scala plugin installed, well, I do have it installed in Intellij.

Comment: No you won't need it. Just create a new SBT project or a new maven project (and add the Scala plugin for Maven) and try.