# Can't install Scaladoc with SBT and Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to scala and am currently trying to setup IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 with the Scala plugin. It has support for SBT. I have simply followed the basic tutorial for creating a new project for SBT here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+SBT

Currently my build.sbt file is:

```
name := "scalasandpit"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test"

autoAPIMappings := true
```

This pulls down various jar binaries, but no sources and no javadoc. I wondered if there is a way to have both sources and javadoc work with IntelliJ and SBT. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Just as a note, I'm not trying to generate my own scaladoc, I'm trying to link in external scaladoc from either jars, directories or URLs

Comment: Creating a SBT project in IDEA can take several minutes in background. Did you wait until the `src` and `src/main/scala` directories are automatically created?

Comment: yeah, that is all done. sbt does the refresh and builds.

Comment: I posted this issue on the jetbrains forums here: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5522253#5522253

Notably, when I create an IDEA project from an existing SBT project, following this process here: http://scalatutorials.com/beginner/2013/07/18/getting-started-with-sbt/
I was able then to choose the "Download sources and docs" using the Import wizard process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two issues: getting sbt to pull down sources and docs, and then getting Idea to show them to you. To solve the former problem see the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html) -- about half way down there's a section called "Download Sources" which tells you what to add to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += 
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc()
```

Comment: BTW, I'm not convinced this is actually the right approach for Idea, and checking the IntelliJ forums may be helpful.

Comment: This did work for the libraryDependencies that aren't part of the standard scala libraries. (for example your solution to adding it for this specific library dependency did work). However I can't get it to work for scala-library.jar and the like.

Comment: @silverdagger : Idea is supposed to pick the doc up automagically if installed. I'm already trying to help somebody with this in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389922/mavericks-intellij-scala-not-configuring-properly/25449383#25449383) and there are earlier threads here for earlier versions of Idea. That person's problem seems to be specific to the Mac version, but you'll see the basic mechanism and what the issues are. Not sure about sources.